# Get first item in each_with_index result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a loop that collects all items with index value of 0 via has_many through scenario.

```
<% @trial.treatment_selections.each do |t| %>
    <% t.establishment_methods.each_with_index do |e, index| %>
        <% if index == 0 %>
            <%= index %> | <%= e.assessment_date %><br />
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This out puts 4 dates of the same value all with the same index of 0. ie.

```
0 | 2018-12-31
0 | 2018-12-31
0 | 2018-12-31
0 | 2018-12-31
```

My questions is, is there a way to grab only to first item in the loop? `e.assessment_date.first`, `e.assessment_date[0]` don't seem to be viable options.

Comment: Do you mean `@trial.treatment_selections.first.establishment_methods.first` ? You could use `each_with_index` in `treatment_selections` and check that it is the first in both levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in different ways. Following your cycle idea, you could use `each_with_index` in your first loop as well:

```
<% @trial.treatment_selections.each_with_index do |t, outer_index| %>
    <% t.establishment_methods.each_with_index do |e, inner_index| %>
        <% if outer_index == 0 && inner_index == 0 %>
            <%= inner_index %> | <%= e.assessment_date %><br />
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But the best way to do it is in just one line

```
0 | <%= @trial.treatment_selections.first&.establishment_methods.first&.assessment_date %>
```

The index will always be `0` when you want to print it.

Comment: First optioned worked as it should. Appreciate the help @byrdEmmanuel.